# I need help joining these two datasets to produce the results on this exercise

Tags: sql

I'm trying to join table 1 and table 2 to create table 3 with using SQL. How would I be able to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you need  a join, count and group by

```
select a.region, b.partnerType, count(*)
from table1 a 
inner join table2 b on a.DistrectID = b.DistrectID
group by  a.region, b.partnerType
```